Fierz Identity in 2+1d
Wikipedia states an example of Fierz Identity, under the assumption of commuting spinors, the $\mathrm{V} \times \mathrm{V}$ product that can be expanded as,
$$
\left(\bar{\chi} \gamma^\mu \psi\right)\left(\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \chi\right)=(\bar{\chi} \chi)(\bar{\psi} \psi)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\bar{\chi} \gamma^\mu \chi\right)\left(\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\bar{\chi} \gamma^\mu \gamma_5 \chi\right)\left(\bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \gamma_5 \psi\right)-\left(\bar{\chi} \gamma_5 \chi\right)\left(\bar{\psi} \gamma_5 \psi\right),
$$
however, this is valid only for commuting spinors in $3+1d$.
My question is whether a similar expression exists in $2+1d$ and $1+1d$ for anti-commuting spinors. Or at least any reference that gives such an expression.
Also, can you add the number of flavors ($N_f$) and colors ($N_c$)?
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fierz_identity

A promos of your last line, If you were summing over flavors/colors, you could simply distribute the sums involved. Try two such.

Review this.

@CosmasZachos I looked at the Review, but it seems they only treat spinors in Euclidean spaces, not Minkowski
